# In Oracle can you create a table that only exists while the database is running?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way in Oracle to create a table that only exists while the database is running and is only stored in memory? So if the database is restarted I will have to recreate the table?

Edit:
I want the data to persist across sessions. The reason being that the data is expensive to recreate but is also highly sensitive.

Using a temporary table would probably help performance compared to what happens today, but its still not a great solution.

Comment: As far as I know, temporary tables in Oracle are persistent; only their data is volatile. Would that be an issue for you?

Comment: That is my issue, I want the data to stick around while the database is up since recreating the data is expensive.

Comment: What is your intention? what do you want to do?

Comment: have you tried to move the table in the buffer pool? if it is expensive to recreate why do you want to dissapear when database is down? Normal tables remains there and you don't need to recreate them at startup. Probably I missunderstood something.

Comment: alter table my_table storage (buffer_pool keep);

Comment: It sounds like you want this table held in memory, and _never_ written to disk, because you do not want the sensitive data to be at risk for disclosure while the database is at rest, yes? I know of no way in Oracle to guarantee that data is not written to disk. Even memory can be written to the swap file, if the Oracle instance is not sized appropriately for the system.

Comment: i am no oracle expert but i wonder if you can create a tablespace in /dev/shm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Oracle's trigger mechanism to invoke a stored procedure when the database starts up or shuts down.

That way you could have the startup trigger create the table, and the shutdown trigger drop it.

You'd probably also want the startup trigger to handle cases where the table exists and truncate it just in case the server stopped suddenly and the shutdown trigger wasn't called.

[Oracle trigger documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm)

Comment: I like this approach with an unlogged table. I may also use the buffer_pool keep above as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a 100% ephemeral table that is usable for the duration of a session (typically shorter than the duration than the database run time) called a TEMPORARY table.  The entire purpose of a table in memory is to make it faster for reading from.  You will have to re-populate the table for each session as the table will be forgotten (both structure and data) once the session completes.

Answer (score 4):

No exactly, no.
Oracle has the concept of a "global temporary table".  With a global temporary table, you create the table once, as with any other table.  The table definition will persist permanently, as with any other table.

The contents of the table, however, will will not be permanent.  Depending on how you define it, the contents will persist for either the life of the session (on commit perserve rows) or the life of the transaction (on commit delete rows).

See the documentation for all the details:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables003.htm#ADMIN11633

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Using Oracle's [Global Temporary Tables](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/TemporaryTables.php), you can create a table in memory and have it delete the data at the end of the transaction, or the end of the session.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have some data that needs to be processed when the database is brought online and left available only as long as the database is online. The only use-case I can think of that would require this is if you're encrypting some data and you want to ensure that the unencrypted data is never written to disk.

If this is actually your use-case, I would recommend forgetting about trying to create your own solution for this and, instead, make use of Oracle's [encrypted tablespaces](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tspaces002.htm#BABBJGAF) or [Transparent Data Encryption](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14268/asotrans.htm).

Comment: Don't laugh but Oracle's encrypted tablespaces and TDE have both been deemed security risks for the environment I'm working in. That's unfortunately outside my control and I've already lost the fight to use them.